# Silverlight RIA Service application - how to get network access?

Tags: silverlight, networking, ria

In my Silverlight application I host a domain service that needs to copy and read files elsewhere on the network.  The problem (at least I think) is that RIA services are running under the ASP.NET account and does not have access to the UNC share I need to get to.  For example, I have a share that looks like this:

> \\SERVER_NAME\Directory\File.TXT

When debugging on my local machine, the user context is the logged in user, so everything works, but when I deploy to my IIS7 server, the user is whatever ASP.NET uses.

How can I allow my service to access files across my domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an appPool in IIS7 with the identity of that pool set to a user with the privileges to do what you want.

I would consider if those privileges constituted a security risk and if the application needed securing.

For more detail and help on appPools please see [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/).